# Counting income and expense in one query in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to count income and expense in one query within Laravel, However, I get errors like:

> Syntax error or access violation

Any suggestions?

```php
$report = $this->Reporting
    ->where('board_id', $id)
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(payment) as `income` WHERE status = 
           "income"'), DB::raw('sum(payment) as `expense` WHERE status = 
           "expense"'), DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M-%Y') new_date"),
        DB::raw('YEAR(date) year, MONTH(date) month'))
    ->groupby('year', 'month')
    ->get();
```

Comment: which concrete error you've got? did you try to dump your query? did you try run such query directly in your DB server?

Comment: Doesn't look like an sql/orm problem. More like a property visibility error on $Reporting.

Comment: $this->Reporting is my db table module name when i place in controller so i cant use more than one time so its less code but you use table name from there

Comment: i am getting syntax error where i user WHERE inside the DB::raw